# Remove scroll bar from ONLY home page

Tags: css, scroll

I would like to know how to remove the scroll bar from my home page ONLY and leave it untouched on every other page.

```
html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information. Are you serving a different style for each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home page has unique class 'home' and its not present for rest of the pages. You can make use of that as below:
Question is not clear (may be because of typo). Am assuming that you don't want to scroll vertically on home page but rest of the pages should be scroll-able vertically.
Code:

```
html{
overflow-y:auto;
}
html .home{
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job.Thank you.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0px!important;
}
```